# radiobutton after select do not fill

Tags: android, radio-button

in android, I write a code  for ask questions from user.answers show in RadioGroup that have multiple RadioButton, but when user click on a RadioButton, that RadioButton does not fill in the graphic.
code of radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener is here:

```
    holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final RadioGroup group, final int checkedId) {

            rb = group.findViewById(checkedId);
            try {
                //set time in mili
                Thread.sleep(500);

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (correctAns.equals(rb.getText())) {
                if (itemList.get(position).getLevel().equals("el"))
                    sumResultEl++;
                else if (itemList.get(position).getLevel().equals("pre"))
                    sumResultPre++;
                else
                    sumResultInter++;
            }
```

there is RecyclerView.my questions show by RecyclerView.
xml of questions is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/question_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                >
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button_answer1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button_answer2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button_answer3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button_answer4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the same color of background as well as of radio button's tint

Try setting RadioGroup background to white

Add below line to your RadioGroup

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

edit: Everything works fine for me here with your provided xml code.
But Thread.sleep(500) pauses your main thread for half second.
Instead use

```
`handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayInMillis);`
```

Also I suspect that your style is modified (colorPrimary, colorAccent etc.) please check that

Comment: But did you try that ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your app theme.
Especially the `colorAccent`. If it is same as colorPrimary then that might be the issue for the graphics